# XAMPP with PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, xampp, postgresql

I'm looking for a package like XAMPP, but instead of MySQL it would use PostgreSQL. I've done some searching and haven't turned up anything other than doing a full server setup of both.

Answer (score 3):

Two packages might suit you:

- BitNami LAPP, MAPP, WAPP: http://bitnami.org/article/apache-php-and-postgresql-all-in-one
- EnterpriseDB Postgres Plus: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/postgres_plus/download.do

Comment: You may use PostgreSQL on top of WAMP Stack or MAMP Stack:
https://bitnami.com/stack/mamp/modules#postgresqladdon